# How to link to section in react toggle menu

Tags: reactjs, scroll, menu, toggle, sections

How do I link to section for each button in the array. Meaning: in stead of numbers in the arrays iconArrayOne and iconArrayTwo , I need to implement links or tags in order to link to a section id for instance to="section3"? 
This array only accepts numbers , not objects.

```
const iconArrayOne = [1, 2, 3];
const iconArrayTwo = [1, 2, 3].reverse();
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/andytran/pen/YGyQRY

HTML

```
#root
```

Javascript:

```
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { Motion, StaggeredMotion, spring } = ReactMotion;
const { noop } = _;

/**
 * <App />
 */
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      active: false,
    }

    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
  }

  _onClick() {
    this.setState({ 
      active: !this.state.active 
    });
  }

  render() {
    const iconArrayOne = [1, 2, 3];
    const iconArrayTwo = [1, 2, 3].reverse();
    const tooltipArrayOne = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
    const tooltipArrayTwo = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'].reverse();

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ButtonGroup>
          <StaggeredMotion
            defaultStyles={[
              { x: -45, o: 0 },
              { x: -45, o: 0 },
              { x: -45, o: 0 },
            ]}
            styles={prevInterpolatedStyles => prevInterpolatedStyles.map((_, i) => {
              return i === prevInterpolatedStyles.length - 1
                ? {
                  x: spring(this.state.active ? 0 : -45, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                  o: spring(this.state.active ? 1 : 0, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                } : {
                  x: spring(prevInterpolatedStyles[i + 1].x, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                  o: spring(prevInterpolatedStyles[i + 1].o, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                };
            })}
          >
            {interpolatingStyles =>
              <ButtonGroup>
                {interpolatingStyles.map((style, i) =>
                  <Button
                    key={i}
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      right: style.x,
                      opacity: style.o,
                      pointerEvents: this.state.active ? 'auto' : 'none',
                    }}
                  >
                    <Tooltip text={tooltipArrayOne[i]} />
                    {iconArrayOne[i]}
                 </Button>
                )}
              </ButtonGroup>
            }
          </StaggeredMotion>

          <Motion
            defaultStyle={{ s: 0.675 }}
            style={{ s: spring(this.state.active ? 1 : 0.675, { stiffness: 330, damping: 14 }) }}
          >
            {interpolatingStyles =>
              <Button 
                className="button--large" 
                onClick={this._onClick} 
                style={{ 
                  transform: 'scale(' + interpolatingStyles.s + ')',
                }}
              >
                <span className={this.state.active ? 'icon active' : 'icon'} />
              </Button>
            }
          </Motion>

          <StaggeredMotion
            defaultStyles={[
              { x: -45, o: 0 },
              { x: -45, o: 0 },
              { x: -45, o: 0 },
            ]}
            styles={prevInterpolatedStyles => prevInterpolatedStyles.map((_, i) => {
              return i === 0
                ? {
                  x: spring(this.state.active ? 0 : -45, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                  o: spring(this.state.active ? 1 : 0, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                } : {
                  x: spring(prevInterpolatedStyles[i - 1].x, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                  o: spring(prevInterpolatedStyles[i - 1].o, { stiffness: 330, damping: 20 }),
                };
            })}
          >
            {interpolatingStyles =>
              <ButtonGroup>
                {interpolatingStyles.map((style, i) =>
                  <Button
                    key={i}
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      left: style.x,
                      opacity: style.o,
                      pointerEvents: this.state.active ? 'auto' : 'none',
                    }}
                  >
                    <Tooltip text={tooltipArrayTwo[i]} />
                    {iconArrayTwo[i]}
                  </Button>
                )}
              </ButtonGroup>
            }
          </StaggeredMotion>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * <Tooltip />
 */
const Tooltip = (props) => <span className="tooltip">{props.text}</span>;

/**
 * <ButtonGroup />
 */
const ButtonGroup = (props) => <div className="button-group" style={props.style}>{props.children}</div>;

/**
 * <Button />
 */
const Button = (props) => <button className={classNames('button', props.className)} style={props.style} onClick={props.onClick || noop}>{props.children}</button>;

/**
 * Target #root and render <App />
 */
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

CSS

```
// $accent: #F1404B;
$accent: #6C2EB9;

// Used by <ButtonGroup />
.button-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

// Used by <Button />
.button {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  background: $accent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(#000, 0.2), 0 2px 0 rgba($accent, 0.2);
  margin: 0 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;

  &--large {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }

  &:hover {
    .tooltip {
      top: -100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}

// Used by inside <Button />
.icon {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: background 0.3s ease;

  &,
  &:before,
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: '';
    transition: all 100ms ease,
      right 100ms 100ms ease,
      left 100ms 100ms ease;
  }

  &:before {
    left: -11px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  &:after {
    right: -11px;
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }

  &.active {
    background: transparent;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;

    &,
    &:before,
    &:after {
      height: 3px;
    }

    &:before,
    &:after {
      width: 20px;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transition: all 100ms ease, 
        width 100ms 100ms ease, 
        transform 300ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.28, 0.55, 0.385, 1.65);
    }

    &:before {
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    }

    &:after {
      right: 50%;
      transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }
}

// Used by <Tooltip />
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80%;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(#000, 0.8);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms ease;
}

// Demo Purposes
body {
  background: #F3F3F3;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you want to have a different `id text` for section rather than a simple number, so i came up with 3 approaches.

**Option 1 (Not fun):** 
Use a static pattern for the sections

Example:

```
<Button
    onClick={((e) => this.scrollTo(e, `section${i}`))}*
   ....
     }}
     >
    <Tooltip text={tooltipArrayTwo[i]} />
       {iconArrayTwo[i]}
</Button>
```

**Option 2 (I would use, quick and time saving if i have limited and know sections):**

Array sectionIds = ['sectionId1', 'divisionid2', 'someOtherSection3'];

```
 <Button
    onClick={((e) => this.scrollTo(e, `${sectionIds[i]}`))} 
      .....      
     >
    <Tooltip text={tooltipArrayTwo[i]} />
       {iconArrayTwo[i]}
</Button>
```

**Option 3 (Time consuming and if sections are dynamic/unknown - most fun too):**

mention a specific attribute in each section along with id

/* Returns all the section IDs based on attribute */
function getSectionIds(){
.... logic here
}

```
  <Button
    onClick={((e) => this.scrollTo(e, `${getSectionsIds[i]}`))} 
      .....      
     >
    <Tooltip text={tooltipArrayTwo[i]} />
       {iconArrayTwo[i]}
</Button>
```

Your button can also show dynamic text for each section based on attribute (fully configurable)

**Note:** scrollTo will be a function which uses Js or JQuery for smooth scrolling.

I Hope i was able to give you an approach you can take :-)

BTW I loved the Menu animation ;-)